# Is this correct reasoning for $V'' \cong V' \cong V$.?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$.
Consider the dual space of $V$, denoted $V'$ defined to be the vector space of all linear functionals on $V$; that is $V'=\mathscr{L}(V,F)$.

Now, if $\dim V=n$, then knowing that $\dim F=1$, we conclude $\dim V'=n\cdot 1=n$.

Moreover, $V'$ and $V$ are vector spaces of the same dimension over same field $F$, therefore $V$ is isomorphic to $V'$. Is this correct reasoning?

Furthermore, $\dim V''$, that is the dual space of the dual space, also has dimension $n$ and is over the field $F$, so $V'' \cong V' \cong V$.

Am I thinking about this correctly?

Comment: Here is another way to think about it. Looking at the simple case of $ax+by$ you can see that if we choose $a$ and $b$ to be the variables instead of $x$ and $y$ that we haven't really changed anything. More generally if we write the functional as  $w^Tv$ for some fixed $w \in V$ you can see pretty clearly that they're isomorphic vector spaces. It's basically just row vectors versus column vectors and almost reduces to notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct in both cases (in finite dimensions).

An interesting tangential point:

There is no 'nice' isomorphism $V'\cong V$. You have to first fix a basis, to explicitly describe this in any easy way. However, there is a 'nice' isomorphism $V''\cong V$, a *natural isomorphism*. Though your arguments are correct, I recommend you try to explicitly describe an isomorphism in both cases $V'\cong V,\,V''\cong V$. There are many, there's no one right answer. However, try to find a 'slick' answer in the latter case, as such a slick answer exists.

I will give hints to both if you wish.

If I remember correctly, if $V$ has countably infinite dimension (and is a normed space) then $V$ is *never* isomorphic to its dual.

Comment: @peanut You're welcome. I'm not sure what the rest of your comment means, though. Are you saying you've already seen proofs that use explicit isomorphisms, but you'd rather use your dimension-counting argument? It really is worth understanding the "canonical" isomorphism $V\cong V''$, as it also plays an important role in functional analysis (loosely, that is linear algebra in infinite dimensions)

Comment: Yes. I deleted that comment, as it didn't make any sense. Thanks. I am going to look into understanding the "canonical" isomorphism V≅V′′ right now.